# How to hide fetch and XHR logs in Cypress 12?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm learning Cypress 12 and wanted to disable fetch and XHR from logging. In my research, I found "[Hide XHR calls on Cypress test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71357705/hide-xhr-calls-on-cypress-test-runner)" which points to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/simenbrekken/3d2248f9e50c1143bf9dbe02e67f5399) but for some reason, it's not working.

My following steps:

root level *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "node",
      "cypress-real-events",
      "cypress-file-upload",
      "cy-verify-downloads"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "./cypress/support/cypress.d.ts"]
}
```

directory tree of:

```
/ 
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
  yarn.lock
  cypress.config.ts
  / cypress
    / support
      / cypress.d.ts
      / e2e.ts
```

contents of *cypress.d.ts*:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface ResolvedConfigOptions {
    hideXHRInCommandLog?: boolean;
  }
}
```

contents of *e2e.ts*:

```
// Hide fetch/XHR requests from command log
if (Cypress.config('hideXHRInCommandLog')) {
  const app = window.top;
  if (
    app &&
    !app.document.head.querySelector('[data-hide-command-log-request]')
  ) {
    const style = app.document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML =
      '.command-name-request, .command-name-xhr { display: none }';
    style.setAttribute('data-hide-command-log-request', '');

    app.document.head.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

still renders the XHR:

[image]

this appears to be a known issue from further research:

- [How to stop (xhr) processes in cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691022/how-to-stop-xhr-processes-in-cypress)
- [Cypress XHR stubbing ignores ajax requests performed with fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534846/cypress-xhr-stubbing-ignores-ajax-requests-performed-with-fetch)
- [Hide XHR requests from the command log](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7362)
- [Cypress don't see requests in Command Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235428/cypress-dont-see-requests-in-command-log)

In Cypress 12 how can I hide XHR and fetch logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an intercept at the top of the test to turn off logging for `fetch` and `xhr`.

```js
cy.intercept({ resourceType: /xhr|fetch/ }, { log: false })
```

See [RouteMatcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher)

> **resourceType** - The resource type of the request. See "Request object properties" for a list of possible values for resourceType.
>
> ```js
> {
>   ...
>   resourceType: 'document' | 'fetch' | 'xhr' | 'websocket' | 'stylesheet'
>              | 'script' | 'image' | 'font' | 'cspviolationreport' | 'ping'
>              | 'manifest' | 'other'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

There is this answer [Hide URL in Cypress Info Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75024546/18366749)

I tried it out, this is the variation that works on a simple 1-fetch test.

Comment out the `Cypress.on("log:changed")` to see it fail.

```js
Cypress.on("log:changed", (log, interactive) => {
  if (log.displayName !== "fetch") return;

  const logs = window.top.document.querySelectorAll("li.command-name-request");
  if (logs.length) {
    const last = [...logs][logs.length - 1];
    last.remove();
  }
});

it("tests that fetch logs are removed from Cypress UI", () => {

  cy.intercept("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").as("fetch");

  cy.visit("/");

  cy.wait("@fetch").then(() => {
    cy.wrap(window.top.document)
      .its("body")
      .find('[data-cy="reporter-panel"]')
      .find("li.command-name-request")
      .should("not.exist");
  });
});
```

You'll have to patch in the XHR types as well, I didn't test that far. Should be something like

```js
if (log.displayName !== "fetch" && log.displayName !== "xhr") return
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the js-doc in `node_modules\cypress\types\cypress.d.ts` for the `log:changed`:

> `event is debounced to prevent it from firing too quickly and too often`.

This is why in some cases, if many `fetch`-requests fire in a short period of time and the event is debounced, the log-entries are batched, it may be not enough to remove only the last entry. In that case, you can do the following instead:

```
// removes all fetch-entries from the panel
Cypress.on("log:changed", (log) => {
  // ignore non-fetch logs
  if (log.displayName !== "fetch") return;

  if (!window.top) return;
  const logs = window.top.document.querySelectorAll("li.command-name-request");
  if (logs.length) {
    // loop over all entries since log:changed-event is debounced to prevent it from firing too quickly and too often
    [...logs].forEach((log) => {
      // remove all fetch-entries from the panel
      if (log.textContent?.includes("(fetch)")) log.remove();
    });
  }
});
```